# StackOverFlow and TransactionTooLarge exceptions when trying to upload a small file to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to Firebase.

```
...
if(image != null){
            storageRef.child("images").child(getUniqueName()).putBytes(compressImage(image, c.getContentResolver()))
...
```

and compressImage method:

```
public static byte[] compressImage(Uri data, ContentResolver resolver) {
   Bitmap bmpSample;
    try {
        bmpSample = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, data);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmpSample.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, out);
        byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();
        Log.d("image size", byteArray.length/1024+"");
        return byteArray;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

"image size" in the log is 81KB which is [smaller than 1MB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38128667/4369107). Can anyone suggest why do I get these exceptions?

```
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 20173896 bytes
                                                                             at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:5453)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:96)
                                                                             at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                                             at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

and:

```
D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT:
The weird thing is that the files do show in the Firebase Storage in the console.

Comment: without image does it work ?

Comment: yes, I've been using the `FirebaseDatabase` and it works fine

Comment: no, i mean now, if you comment it out,

storageRef.child("images").child(getUniqueName()).putBytes(compressImage(image, c.getContentResolver())),

does it work ok?

Comment: I ran your code on an older KitKat device.  It successfully uploaded an image that compressed to 150KB.  Add more `Log` statements and post more of your logcat output so we can see the context in which the exceptions occur.