# how do I store multiple images Url in Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have uploaded multiple images in firebase storage and now I want to add their urls in data so along with other data.  How do i do it? I am getting all urls in log but app crashes when i try to use the following code?

```
storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog Data");

final DatabaseReference newBlog = databaseReference.push();
 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)

        {
            if (imageUri != null) {

                final StorageReference ref = filePath.child(fileName[i]);

                final int y = i;
                ref.putFile(imageUri[i])
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                                  @Override
                                                  public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                                      progressDialog.cancel();
                                                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploaded successfuly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                   downloadUri[y] = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                                      Log.i("DownlaodUri ", "downlaod URi is :"+downloadUri[y].toString());

                                                     newBlog.child("image_"+y+1).setValue(downloadUri[y]);




                                                  }


                                              }

                        )
```

I also tried to use another for loop after first loop to store urls. It saves all data in database but doesnt store urls.

This is how I tried it.

```
}// end of upper for loop
       DatabaseReference newBlog = databaseReference.push();
        newBlog.child("title").setValue(title);
        newBlog.child("desc").setValue(desc);


        for(int i =  0; i<list.size(); i++) {

           newBlog.child("image_"+i+1).setValue(downloadUri[i]);
       }
       newBlog.child("location").setValue(location);
```

> It stores all the values except images.

After storing all image url in database how am I supposed to fetch all images as I wont be knowing number of images in database so I cant make certain number of imageview ? how do i get to know that how many child names "ïmages_1", "images_2" a node has?

Logcat.

```
identical 617 lines
05-22 15:07:22.736 29586-29586/com.example.anant.ExampleE/UncaughtException:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)



I/zygote64: Background concurrent copying GC freed 635684(49MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 44% free, 29MB/53MB, paused 377us total 111.410ms
05-22 15:07:22.737 29586-29586/com.example.anant.ExampleE/UncaughtException:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)

I/chatty: uid=10162(com.example.anant.Example) identical 1231 lines
05-22 15:07:23.524 29586-29586/com.example.anant.ExampleE/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.anant.Example, PID: 29586
                                                                             java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:128)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zzca(Unknown Source:132)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbw(Unknown Source:263)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzbz(Unknown Source:0)
```

Comment: please add the logcat showing the error

Comment: I have added the logcat. Please check.

Comment: the error is something other than the question you asked.  just need to push each items to add all images no need to set image1,image2 etc  onDataChange  dataSnapShot.getChilderCount() will fetch how many images are added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add .toString when Passing downloadUri to setvalue(). Thats what caused overFlow exception.

Refer this question for details

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/38128667/8457096

ps. I don't know why people downvote question if they cant answer it.

Answer (score 0):

```
storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog Data");

//final DatabaseReference newBlog = databaseReference.push();//not required
 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)

    {
        if (imageUri != null) {

            final StorageReference ref = filePath.child(fileName[i]);

            final int y = i;
            ref.putFile(imageUri[i])
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                                  progressDialog.cancel();
                                                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploaded successfuly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                               downloadUri[y] = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                                  Log.i("DownlaodUri ", "downlaod URi is :"+downloadUri[y].toString());

        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        map.put("image_url",downloadUri[y]);
                                                 databaseReference.push().updateChildren(map);




                                              }


                                          }

                    )
```

please try to edit the code like above and try..

Comment: this error is caused by some memory overflow exception not caused by firebase may be caused by some listview adapter holding all the images to be uploaded

Comment: But when I remove line newBlog.child("image_").setValue(downloadUri[y]); It works perfectly.

Also the urls are not added even after the end of for loop. check quest pls

Comment: DatabaseReference newBlog = databaseReference.getInstance().getReference().child("Images");
       


        for(int i =  0; i<list.size(); i++) {
           newBlog.push().child("image_url").setValue(downloadUri[i]);
       }              //please add this code by replacing the second part of your code

Comment: It was stupid mistake I did. I forgot to add .toString when passing downloadUri to setvalue()  instead did it in log. its working now.
last question
How do get number of images stored in a node ?

Comment: Add Using newBlog.push().child("image_url").setValue(download url in string);                                                                                                             Then inside onDataChange of addValueEventListener call dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() to get no of urls added