# Getting StackOverflow exception trying whereIn clause in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch documents thats belongs to a certain user and just documents which contains status from 1,2,4,5,6  , but instead of getting the documents I'm getting a weird error, this is the code which fetchs for orders with just that status into Firestore

```
suspend fun getIncompletedOrders(): Resource<List<Order>> {
        val reminderList = mutableListOf<Order>()
        val query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("orders").whereEqualTo("uid",FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser).whereIn("status",
            listOf(1,2,4,5,6)).get().await()
        for(documents in query.documents){
            reminderList.add(documents.toObject(Order::class.java)!!)
        }
        return Resource.Success(reminderList)
    }
```

This code is throwing the following error

> java.lang.StackOverFlowError: stack size 1041KB at com.gogle.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$ErrorPath.toString(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:1155)

Firebase Structure

```
   |_ orders
            |_ docID
                   |_ status: 2
                   |_ uid: userID
```

### Order

```
data class Order(
    val cart: MutableList<Cart> = mutableListOf(),
    val shopName:String = "",
    val deliveryPrice: Int = 0,
    val wantDelivery: Boolean = false,
    val address:String = "",
    val paymentMethod: Int = 0,
    val total: Int = 0,
    val uid: String = "",
    val status: Int = 0,
)
```

I dont really know where the problem is

Comment: Please edit the question to show the source for Order.

Comment: Doing it right now @DougStevenson

Comment: I have posted the model class @DougStevenson , thanks for your time

Comment: If you can reproduce this reliably in a simple test app, I would file a bug.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk

Comment: Yes, I have tested it in a sample project and is not working as expected

Comment: any update on this @DougStevenson

Comment: I don't have an update.  As I said, I think you should file a bug on GitHub using the link I provided.

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson , I have found the issue, I was trying to match the UID with currentUser, I needed to pass currentUser.uid to match the query

Answer (score 0):

Seems as the document you are trying to pass to your collection is too big, according with [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html) :

> "The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently
> 1Mb, which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process.
> Consequently this exception can be thrown when there are many
> transactions in progress even when most of the individual transactions
> are of moderate size."

On this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128241/firebase-google-causes-java-lang-stackoverflowerror) was answered a similar question, maybe you want to take a look on it.

Could you share further details about the document you are handling and the complete trace error?

Comment: but the document just has 2 fields, thats weird and there is only one document, also it should handle a rejection in the coroutine instead of doing this crash

Comment: Just to confirm could you share the complete structure of Order? Just as a kind reminder objects that are coming from the database, it requires that any objects in use, to have a public no-argument constructor, you can check that on this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write